# Using Powershell to upload large file to OneDrive

Tags: powershell-3.0, onedrive

I am trying to use PowerShell to upload large backup files (~1-2GB). I am using an HTTP Post to try and put the file but am getting this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At C:\Repository\Powershell\PS-LaptopBackup\OneDrive Upload\main.ps1:61 char:71
+     $bak_files | foreach-object { Write-Host "UPLOADING: $($_.Name)"; Invoke-Res ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

the command I am using to upload is

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($upload_location)/$($_.Name)`?access_token=$AccessToken" -Method Put -InFile $_.FullName -TimeoutSec 3600
```

The command works but it throws that error. I assume it is because the HTTP connection fails. Is there another way to interact with OneDrive?

Thanks,
Nat

Comment: you could try to use bitstransfer which allows automatic retries and asynchronous transfers. http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd819420.aspx

Comment: Powershell has problems with this, there are a few other questions like this on SO. This one worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235806/upload-big-files-via-http

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use POST instead of PUT as on there api documentation i found:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx#download_a_file.

If you were able to solve this can you please post the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

**Upload large file using power shell script**

```
Function UploadLargeFileInChunk ($Ctx, $TargetFolder, $TargetFileURL, $FilePath, $FileChunkSizeInMB=5) {
            
# Get the name of the file.
$FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FilePath)
 
# File object.
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File] $Upload
     
# Calculate block size in bytes.
$BlockSize = $FileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024
 
# Get the size of the file.
$FileSize = (Get-Item $FilePath).length
 
if ($FileSize -le $BlockSize)
{
# Use regular upload.
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($FilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $TargetFileURL
$Upload = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Ctx.Load($Upload)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
return $Upload
}
else
{  
       
# Use chunk by chunk file upload.
# Each block upload requires a unique ID.
$UploadId = [GUID]::NewGuid()
$BytesUploaded = $null
$Fs = $null
$FileSizeInMB = [math]::Round($(($FileSize/1024)/1014),2)
Try
{
$Fs = [System.IO.File]::Open($FilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
$br = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($Fs)
$buffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($BlockSize)
$lastBuffer = $null
$fileoffset = 0
$totalBytesRead = 0
$bytesRead
$first = $true
$last = $false
# Read data from file system in blocks. 
while(($bytesRead = $br.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
{
$totalBytesRead = $totalBytesRead + $bytesRead
# You've reached the end of the file.
if($totalBytesRead -eq $FileSize)
{
$last = $true
# Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
$lastBuffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($bytesRead)
[array]::Copy($buffer, 0, $lastBuffer, 0, $bytesRead)
}
 
try
{
#Show upload file progress
$UploadSizeInBM = [math]::Round($(($totalBytesRead/1024)/1014),2)
Write-Progress -Activity "Uploading file $FileName" -Status "$UploadSizeInBM out of $FileSizeInMB MB uploaded"
}
Catch{}
 
If($first)
{
$ContentStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
 
# Add an empty file.
$fileInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$fileInfo.ContentStream = $ContentStream
$fileInfo.Url = $TargetFileURL
$fileInfo.Overwrite = $true
$Upload = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($fileInfo)
$Ctx.Load($Upload)
 
# Start upload by uploading the first slice.
                     
$s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer) 
                     
# Call the start upload method on the first slice.
$BytesUploaded = $Upload.StartUpload($UploadId, $s)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                     
# fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
$fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
                     
# You can only start the upload once.
$first = $false
 
}
Else
{
# Get a reference to your file.
$Upload = $Ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFileURL);
                     
If($last) {
                         
# Is this the last slice of data?
$s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($lastBuffer)                        
 
# End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
$Upload = $Upload.FinishUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                          
# Large file upload complete. Return the file object for the uploaded file.

return $Upload                       
}
else
{                        
$s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer)
                         
# Continue sliced upload.
$BytesUploaded = $Upload.ContinueUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                         
# Update fileoffset for the next slice.
$fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
                         
}
}
                 
}  #// while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
}
Catch
{
Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
}
Finally {        
if ($Fs -ne $null)
{
$Fs.Dispose()
}
         
}
}
return $null
}
 
 
#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
  
#Specify local folder path
$LocalFolder = "C:\UploadFolder"
  
#Specify SharePoint or OneDrive site admin account
$AdminAccount = "emailid.com"
$AdminPass = "abc123!"
   
#Specify SharePoint Online Site URL or User's OneDrive Site URL
$SiteURL = "https://<your tenant name>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username_domainame_com"
$DocumentLibrary ="Documents"
$TargetFolderName ='' #Leave empty to target root folder
 
#Connect and Load SharePoint Library and Root Folder
$SecPwd = $(ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPass -asplaintext -force) 
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($AdminAccount,$SecPwd) 
$Ctx.credentials = $Credentials
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocumentLibrary)
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.Load($List.RootFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
# Setting Target Folder
$TargetFolder = $null;
$TargetFolderRelativeUrl;
If($TargetFolderName) {
$TargetFolderRelativeUrl = $List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl+"/"+$TargetFolderName
$TargetFolder = $Ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFolderRelativeUrl)
$Ctx.Load($TargetFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
if(!$TargetFolder.Exists){
Throw  "$TargetFolderName - the target folder doest not exist in the root folder."
}
} Else {
$TargetFolder = $List.RootFolder
$TargetFolderRelativeUrl = $TargetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
}
  
# Get folders and sub folders from source location
$folders= @()
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -Path $LocalFolder -Attributes Directory))
{
$folders +=($file.FullName).replace($LocalFolder+"\",'')
}
   
# Create folders and sub-folders in the destination location
Write-Progress -activity "Creating folder structure in OneDrive" -status "Creating Folder"
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
$subfolder_names = $folder.split("\")
$subfolder = $TargetFolder.Folders.Add($subfolder_names[0])
$Ctx.Load($subfolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
for ($i = 1; $i -le ($subfolder_names.Count-1) ; $i++)
{
$subfolder = $subfolder.folders.Add($subfolder_names[$i])
$Ctx.Load($subfolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
}
  
#Read all files recursively from the local folder and upload into corresponding SharePoint or OneDrive folder.
$i = 1
$Files = (Dir $LocalFolder -File -Recurse)
$TotoalFiles = $Files.Length
ForEach($File in $Files)
{
Try
{
Write-Progress -activity "Uplading $File" -status "$i out of $TotoalFiles completed"
# Target file URL with same folder structure
$TargetFileURL = $TargetFolderRelativeUrl +(($file.FullName).Replace($LocalFolder,'')).Replace("\","/")
 
$UploadFile = UploadLargeFileInChunk -Ctx $Ctx -TargetFolder $TargetFolder -TargetFileURL $TargetFileURL -FilePath $File.FullName
}
catch {
Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -Forground "Red"
}
$i++
}
write-host "Backup Uploaded Successfully" ;
```