# Powershell read file in chunks

Tags: powershell, ftp

I've had a script written in Powershell which transferred a file via FTP which worked fine by using:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($backup_app_data)
```

But this stopped working once the file size reached 2Gb, by throwing an error saying that this method is limited to reading files up to this size.

> Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "The file is
>   too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less
>   than 2 gigabytes in size.

Now, I'm trying to modify my script and use an alternate approach with [**Read**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx), which from what I understand will allow me to read the file in chunks and then write those chunks and so on.

Unfortunately although the script I've modified seems to be working, since a file is created on my FTP location, there is no data being transferred and no error is thrown by the script.

There is just a 0kb file created in the destination folder and the script ends.

I've tried to do some debugging, but I can't seem to find the issue. Below is the code I'm currently using.

```
$file = 'G:\Backups\DATA_backup_2016_09_05.zip'
$dest_name = 'DATA_backup_2016_09_05.zip'

$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($ftp+$dest_name)
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$ftp.UsePassive = $true

# determine the size of the file
$file_size = (Get-Item $file).length
$chunk_size = 512mb

$bytes_to_read = $file_size
$iterations = $file_size / $chunk_size
$iter = 0

$fstream = [System.IO.FileStream]
[byte[]] $byte_array 

while ($bytes_to_read > 0){
    if($iterations > 1) {
        $content = $fstream.Read($byte_array, $iter, $chunk_size)
        }
    else {
        $content = $fstream.Read($byte_array, $iter, $bytes_to_read)
    }

    $ftp.ContentLength = $content.Length

    $rs = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
    $rs.Write($content, 0, $content.Length)

    # keep the loop going
    $iter = $iter + 1
    $iterations = $iterations - 1
    $bytes_to_read = $bytes_to_read - $chunk_size
}

$rs.Close()
$rs.Dispose()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload BIG files via HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235806/upload-big-files-via-http) - While for HTTP, it uses the same API, the `WebRequest` and streams, so the loop from the [answer by the @vvchik](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33253233/850848) can be used for FTP too.

Comment: I suspect you need to get rid of your *iterations* variable, since in general you can't tell how many reads you are going to need up-front since you won't necessarily get as many bytes as you try to read.

Comment: Have you tried using `Get-Content -Raw` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that PowerShell uses `-gt` rather than `>`...

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I'm currently working on a version of the script based on the suggested solution from the other question. I'll post my findings and hopefully a working script as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, based on the suggestions in the comment section and using as an example [**the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33253233/1266737) from the possible duplicate [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235806/upload-big-files-via-http), I managed to find the solution myself.

Below is the code I used to transfer via FTP a .zip archive which was 3.74Gb.

```
$ftp_addr = "ftp://ftp.somerandomwebsite.com/folder1/"
$user = "usr"
$pass = "passwrd"
$bufSize = 256mb

# ... missing code where I identify the file I want to FTP ... #

# Initialize connection to FTP
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($ftp_addr + $backup_file + ".zip")
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

$ftp.Timeout = -1              #infinite timeout
$ftp.ReadWriteTimeout = -1     #infinite timeout

$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$ftp.UsePassive = $true

$requestStream = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($file_to_ftp)
$chunk = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

while ( $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($chunk, 0, $bufSize) ){
    $requestStream.write($chunk, 0, $bytesRead)
    $requestStream.Flush()
}

$fileStream.Close()
$requestStream.Close()
```

So far, this code has worked flawlessly for about multiple (20+) attempts. I hope it helps others!