# Teamcity agent can't upload to artifactory using powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity, artifactory, powershell-4.0, teamcity-9.0

I'm trying to upload from teamcity to artifactory using powershell and nant. I've tried two methods using `Invoke-WebRequest` as well as newing up a `WebClient`. Webclient.UploadFile fails like this:

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "An exception
>   occurred during a WebClient request."

While `Invoke-WebRequest` fails like this:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.

If I run either of them manually from that machine, it works. If it start powershell as the teamcity agent service user like this

```
Start powershell -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

and then run the code manually, it works. Only when teamcity is actually trying to do the deploy does it fail every time. I've applied the

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

fix, I've applied the

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = {$true}
```

fix, and it always works when I run it manually but never works when it runs through teamcity. What is going on?

Comment: What do you see in the artifactory 'request.log' after the failure?

Comment: @Ariel When called manually, both `Invoke-WebRequest` and `WebClient` show normal entries in Admin -> System Logs. When called through teamcity, neither of them create any entries.

Comment: Do you have any proxy in front of Teamcity? It looks like it's a proxy issue that blocks the request

Comment: @Ariel not that I know of. If it were, I would think the call would fail when I ran it manually from the teamcity agent, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a much larger script from another project that uses `WebClient` to attempt a 'checksum deploy' to see if the artifact has changed before attempting the actual deploy using code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323495/2476260).