# How to Modify Powershell script to use client SSL certificate?

Tags: powershell

The original poster ("Ralph") provided a script for uploading a ZIP file, as an answer (on Sep 8, 2021 at 5:44) in this older SO thread:

[Powershell is unable to upload zip file over ~50MB using Multipart form-data to REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038508/powershell-is-unable-to-upload-zip-file-over-50mb-using-multipart-form-data-to)

That script that he provided uses HTTP BASIC authentication (via sending a Authorization HTTP header with the request) I think, but I was wondering if it would be possible to modify that script to use client certificate authentication instead, and if so, can someone explain how?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Do not get TLS and Authentication confused.  Both use certificates.  TLS (sometimes referred to by predecessor SSL) is performed before the HTTP Request is sent to establish an encrypted connection.  Authentication is performed after the connection is completed which checks the user credentials.  Credentials verifies the user login from a password server.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you're trying to do? Upload multipart data on a server requiring authentication via https client certificates?