# Problem trying to use Powershell to upload a ZIP file to a Spring boot application (replicating working Curl)

Tags: spring-boot, powershell, curl

We are able to upload a ZIP file containing an zipped LDIF file to a small Spring Boot app, using the following curl command:

curl -k -X POST -F "file=@/dev/Cservice.zip;type=application/zip" https://sag01.xxaws.com:10006/Cservice --cert /dev/axis.pem --key /gx/dev/axis.key

The Spring Boot app receives the ZIPPED LDIF file, unzips it, and then does some processing based on the the lines in the unzipped LDIF file.

But in some environments, they don't have Linux, so they cannot use Curl, so I am now trying to implement a powershell script to perform the same upload as that curl command, and I found this thread older Stackoverflow thread ([Powershell is unable to upload zip file over ~50MB using Multipart form-data to REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038508/powershell-is-unable-to-upload-zip-file-over-50mb-using-multipart-form-data-to)) while searching for how to accomplish that.

I have been trying to use the 1st powershell script posted by "Ralph" in that earlier SO thread, at [Powershell is unable to upload zip file over ~50MB using Multipart form-data to REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038508/powershell-is-unable-to-upload-zip-file-over-50mb-using-multipart-form-data-to)), but modified for our environment (the main difference is we are using certificate authentication)_

Here is my current attempt at the powershell:

```
# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038508/powershell-is-unable-to-upload-zip-file-over-50mb-using-multipart-form-data-to

Write-output "RUNNING: 8from-stackoverflow.ps1"

$Uri = 'https://sag01.gxaws.com:10006/CService'

$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("G:\Dev\CService.zip");
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('utf-8')
$fileEnc = $enc.GetString($fileBytes)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -method POST -TimeoutSec 999999 -Certificate (Get-PfxCertificate axisWithKey.pfx) -SkipCertificateCheck `
-Headers @{ "accept"="*/*"} `
-ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundaryT2XycANuthCIUwGk" `
-Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("--WebKitFormBoundaryT2XycANuthCIUwGk$([char]13)$([char]10)Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"CService.zip`"$([char]13)$([char]10)Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed$([char]13)$([char]10)$([char]13)$([char]10))$fileEnc($([char]13)$([char]10)--    WebKitFormBoundaryT2XycANuthCIUwGk--$([char]13)$([char]10)"))
```

When I run the above powershell script, I am tailing the app log that is receiving the upload, and it looks like the powershell script is trying to upload the "CService.zip" file, and the spring boot app is seeing the upload request, and I can see binary data that appears to be the zip file.  Here's the beginning of the logging of the ZIP file when the powershell script runs (I HOPE the lines below appear):

```
--WebKitFormBoundaryT2XycANuthCIUwGk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="CService.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed

ï¿½*T*ï¿½d~ï¿½ï¿½tbï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Z▒¿½nï¿½no4ï¿½lÏ¢Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½y~tï¿½yï¿½rï¿½aï¿½ï¿½ï¿m?mï¿½í��ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½lï¿½_ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½^^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

However after the app receives the ZIP file it is supposed to unzip the contents and then log the lines, and it appear it is not able to do that:

```
2024-03-14 18:12:58,048 DEBUG m.n.g.m.c.u.StringUtils [https-jsse-nio-8888-exec-2] LDIF before reMap method:
2024-03-14 18:12:58,048 DEBUG m.n.g.m.c.u.StringUtils [https-jsse-nio-8888-exec-2] LDIF after reMap method:
2024-03-14 18:12:58,048 DEBUG m.n.g.m.c.s.LDAPService [https-jsse-nio-8888-exec-2] Lidf entries count = 0
```

I have looked at the same server-side app logging when I run the working Curl command and the logging where it outputs the binary data looks quite different from when I run the powershell script.

The following is a snippet of that logging when the curl is run:

```
2024-03-14 18:38:50,916 DEBUG o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog [https-jsse-nio-8888-exec-9] Received [--------------------------a18e445ef02489d2^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="CService.zip"^M
Content-Type: application/zip^M
^M
PK^C^D^T^@^@^@^H^@QmuVe^XÂ<86>(^O^@^@'~^B^@^S^@^@^@CService.ldif<9a>]kT  ^VEß^Cù^Où^A*u¿êC^P&¦¡q µiõa<9e><86>2Vb^M±*T*Íd~ýÜtb<8e><8c>û<84>^^Z^O^[ön<90>no4®lÏ¢S¬ú¸y~tºyñrûaòå<9f>é³^?m?m<9e>í<9e><9d>ÿûr^?^Z<8f><9f>l¯_üºÚ^^¬<9e>¼yÿâõÏÇ·ÿúiûÓ<93>7/Þ?{ûìèçíï«Ýæój³^?ròâýÛÃ<83
```

Also, I noticed that the Content-length when I run the powershell is about double the length when I run the Curl.

So I think that I must be doing something wrong with the part of the powershell script that is encoding the ZIP file?  Or maybe the Curl upload to the spring boot app works because Curl is doing a different kind of encoding or something?

I hope that someone here might be able to help, as I have been trying to get this working for a few days now, and I feel like I'm getting further from a solution rather than closer, so I decided to try post here.

If there are ANY questions, please let me know and I will try to answer them!

Thanks in advance,
Jim

EDIT:  This is what finally worked per suggestions from mklement0 (in the comments):

```
#FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78162873/problem-trying-to-use-powershell-to-upload-a-zip-file-to-a-spring-boot-applicati
#and:
#FROM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4#example-5-submit-a-multipart-form-data-file

$FilePath = 'G:\Dev\CService.zip'
$URL = 'https://sag02.xxaws.com:10006/CService'

Write-output "ZIP File: $FilePath"
Write-output "URL: $URL"

$FieldName = 'file'

$ContentType = 'application/zip'

$FileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)

$FileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new('form-data')

$FileHeader.Name = $FieldName

$FileHeader.FileName = Split-Path -leaf $FilePath

$FileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($FileStream)

$FileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $FileHeader

$FileContent.Headers.ContentType = [System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue]::Parse($ContentType)

$MultipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$MultipartContent.Add($FileContent)

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Body $MultipartContent -Method POST -Uri $URL -TimeoutSec 999999 -Certificate (Get-PfxCertificate geoaxisWithKey.pfx) -SkipCertificateCheck

Write-output $Response
```

EDIT2:  Documenting testing working vs. "simplified" example from mcklment0:

I tried the "simplified" version that mklement0 mentioned and that "simplified" version did not work.  FYI, the following shows what I think the difference was (in the "Content-Disposition"):

```
GOOD:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=CService.zip^M
Content-Type: application/zip^M


vs. BAD/Simplified:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=CService.zip; filename*=utf-8''CService.zip^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
```

Comment: @mklement0 - we are aware of that, and have been asking which Windows version they (the users) are using, but there's a good chance they may not have the appropriate version :(...  Thanks,

Comment: On that old SO thread that I included, there was an example posted 2 days ago by Mike Anthony/Eric Aya, that is similar to that example 5.  I think that because I am dealing with binary/ZIP files there are some special differences that are making it harder to get working.  Thanks though!

Comment: mklement0 - I am confused :(...  that example 5 was dealing with text/plain file, correct?  Whereas a ZIP file would be binary.  So I think that I was agreeing with you (and also mentioned that even though I don't know what is correct, that it seemed like the encoding in the example I was following was problematic.  But I don't know what needs to be changed in the code that I posted to get it work with the ZIP file... :(

Comment: mklement0 - OH!  So are you saying that you think that would work with the ZIP file?

Comment: @mklement0 - Sorry it took so long - we were having some kind of networking problem or something in our dev environment...nothing was working for a while but I had to bounce a couple machines to get them back... so now I tested with the example 5 style code and.... GENIUS!!  IT WORKS!!!  Can you post an answer and then I'll click on it???  THANKS!!

Comment: Thanks - i just did (added to OP) - can you add an answer please ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**:

There may be no need to translate your [`curl`](https://curl.se/) call to its `Invoke-WebRequest` equivalent:

- Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019 and above now come with `curl.exe` (and `tar.exe`), so you can generally use existing `curl` commands (small adjustments for PowerShell's syntax may be needed) - just make sure you specify the executable as `curl.exe`, not just `curl`, because the latter is a built-in alias for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet in Windows PowerShell.

Read on if you want / need a translation to `Invoke-WebRequest` nonetheless.

---

The following is adapted from [example 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#example-5-submit-a-multipart-form-data-file) of the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) help topic, which shows how to upload a given file (whatever its content, including *binary* content) as a multipart/form-data submission:

```bash
$url = 'https://sag02.xxaws.com:10006/CService'

# Prepare the metadata of the file to upload
$filePath = 'G:\Dev\CService.zip' # Be sure to specify a *full path*.
$contentType = 'application/zip'  # Identify the media type (file type).

# Create a content-disposition header for the file.
$fileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new('form-data')
$fileHeader.Name = 'file' # form field name.
$fileHeader.FileName = Split-Path -Leaf $filePath # file name

# Create a stream-content object with the file's binary data
# and the content-disposition header.
$fileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new(
  [System.IO.FileStream]::new($filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
)
$fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $fileHeader
$fileContent.Headers.ContentType = $contentType

# Create a multipart form data instance with the the stream-content object
# of the file to upload (as the only part).
$multiPartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$multiPartContent.Add($fileContent)

# Call Invoke-WebRequest with the multipart form data as the -Body argument.
$response = 
  Invoke-WebRequest -Body $multiPartContent -Method POST -Uri $url -TimeoutSec 999999 -Certificate (Get-PfxCertificate geoaxisWithKey.pfx) -SkipCertificateCheck

# Output the response.
$response
```

The following *simplified* version, taken from [example 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#example-6-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission), MAY also work:

- *Update*: It did *not* work in your specific case, as shown in the "Edit 2" section of your question: The per-file `Content-Type` field seemingly *invariably* becomes the generic `application/octet-stream`, so the approach would only work if the target server *inferred* the specific media type (e.g. `application/zip`) from the filename extension in the `filename` attribute of the per-file `Content-Disposition` field.

```bash
$url = 'https://sag02.xxaws.com:10006/CService'
$filePath = 'G:\Dev\CService.zip' # Be sure to specify a *full path*.
$form = @{
  file = Get-Item -LiteralPath $filePath
}
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Form $form -Uri $url -Method Post
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("G:\Dev\CService.zip");`
> `$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('utf-8')`
> `$fileEnc = $enc.GetString($fileBytes)`

Note that **it is fundamentally impossible to represent *arbitrary binary data* (in essence, an array of *bytes*) *as a UTF-8 string***, because not all bytes are valid characters in UTF-8, notably not arbitrary bytes with values >= `0x80` (`128`)

The following round-trip example demonstrates this:

```bash
# Try to encode byte values 64, 128 as a UTF-8 string, 
# and decode back to bytes.
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(
  [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([byte[]] (64, 128))
)
```

Output:

```bash
64
239
191
189
```

Note how the invalid-as-UTF-8 byte `128` turned into *multiple* bytes on decoding.
Specifically, the 3-byte sequence `239`, `191`, `189` is the encoding of the `�` Unicode character (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, [`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd)), representing an *invalid character*.

Comment: mklement0 - FYI, I added info from testing the "simplified" version to the OP.  Thanks again!

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, @user555303. I've updated the answer accordingly. Bummer that you seemingly cannot specify a per-file media type with the simplified approach - it would make things much easier.